# How can I generate the same random number in JavaScript and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, random, mersenne-twister

In Python, if I use this code:

```
import random
random.seed(123)
print(random.random())
```

The first random number will always be `0.052363598850944326`, since I'm giving it the same seed every time I run the program.

JavaScript doesn't have a built-in way to use seeds. I've tried out a JavaScript script called [mersenne-twister.js](https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494), since that's the type of PRNG that Python uses. But even if I use the same seed, I get a different result than I do in Python.

```
var m = new MersenneTwister(123);
m.genrand_int32();
```

That code will always return `0.6964691872708499` the first time that it's run.

How can I use a given seed to get the same random number in both Python and JavaScript?

Comment: Since you have the source code to at least one of them, translate it into Python and if you do it right, the numbers produced should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This library/plugin worked for me when I compared the Python output to the JavaScript output.

https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom

Comment: Using `Math.seedrandom(123);
document.write(Math.random());`, I got `0.047035554534303387`. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator, you could use something like this, using the decimals of sinus function.

In python:

```
import math
def simple_random(precision=10000):
    i = 1
    while 1:
        x = math.sin(i) * precision
        yield x - math.floor(x)
        i += 1
```

In Javascript:

```
var i = 1;
function simple_random(precision=10000) {
    x = Math.sin(i++) * precision;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
}
```

If you want to vary seeds, you could use something like sin(a * i + b) rather than sin(i) or a * sin(i + b), it's up to you to find something good enough.